# Connect to Oracle using ADO

Tags: oracle, delphi, ado

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle Server using ADO and Oracle Wallet,

First of all, my wallet IS working. I have tested it using

```
SQLPLUS /@DDKTEST
```

If I provide username and password in my connection string it works fine:

```
Provider=MSDAORA;Password=<my password>;User ID=<My user ID>;Data Source=DDKTEST;Persist Security Info=True
```

But I'm stoked when I need to make a Connection String for Oracle Waller
I've tried the following:

```
Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=DDKTEST;Persist Security Info=True
```

But it doesn't work.

So in short: I need a connection string for ADO, in order for connection to Oracle using my Wallet.

Comment: ancient MSDAORA provider is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-oracle?view=sql-server-2017) for ages, you should not use it. [Download](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odacdeploy-4242173.html) and install the Oracle driver

Comment: And using that driver, what would the connectionstring be

Comment: "*But it doesn't work*' - Did you get any error? (implied question: which one?)

Comment: See https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-provider-for-ole-db-oraoledb/

Comment: Thank you @WernfriedDomscheit  I have looked at that site, but they don't address Oracle Wallet.

Comment: @GolezTrol I have an syntax error. So in short: I need a Connectionstring for ADO using Oracle Wallet

Comment: Having a specific error message and/or error code will help us pinpoint your specific problem and find the correct solution solution. I thought this wouldn't need to be explained to someone like yourself, who has been developing for over 20 years and is a member of SO for almost 5 years.

Comment: [OracleConnection.ConnectionString Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection.connectionstring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_OracleClient_OracleConnection_ConnectionString) and [OraOLEDB-Specific Connection String Attributes](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/OLEDB/using.htm#sthref55) may help you. Looks like the old MS provider does not support system authentication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The connection string that we are using with wallets is:

```
Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=TNSName;OSAuthent=1;
```

We use this successfully with TADOConnection in Delphi (first XE5, now 10).

Where TNSName is an alias as defined in TNSNames.ora. I must note that we use a different provider (reflected in the provider name, `OraOLEDB.Oracle`), and I don't know if this will also work with the outdated and deprecated `MSDAORA`.

We did use MSDAORA before, but switched to OraOLEDB before we started using the wallets. I do remember that it was quite primitive and didn't even support BLOBs, so I'm not very confident it will support wallets at all.

Comment: I'll try it out.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. That was exactly what I needed.